# java with and without if difference

Tags: java, sockets, if-statement

I had a strange problem with Java (solved). I'm asking this because i'm curious of what's going on there.

What's the difference between:

```
if(Transfers.protoSendLong(output, date.getTime())){}
```

and simply

```
Transfers.protoSendLong(output, date.getTime());
```

The difference I see is that the 1st works and the 2nd don't :S
Is there any difference on execution?

I don't think you need to know what protoSendLong() is about to answer. If you need it, just ask.

---

EDIT:

You have the code of the method here. That's the most I can give you.

```
public static boolean protoSendLong(ObjectOutputStream output, long x) {
    boolean r = false;

    try {
        output.writeLong(x);

        r = true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Transfers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return r;
```

}

Comment: Can you build a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) ?

Comment: When you say "works" are you referring to the side effects of `protoSendLong`?

Comment: put ; at the end in second case =)

Comment: @dystroy I don't think the code can't be simplified, and i'm not sure i have permission to lend it anyway.

Comment: @hexafraction Yes, the server sends what he has to send correctly. In the 2nd example, the client keeps waiting forever to receive.

Comment: @Leonidos oh that's a mistake, in my program the ; is being written correctly.

Comment: @JavainJavakain What you give us doesn't make sense. That's why I ask for enough code to possibly explain your problem. Said otherwise : SSCCE or it didn't happen.

Comment: @JavainJavakain Any byte-code manipulation going on there? A (faulty) byte code manipulation would be the only sensible explanation I could come up with.

Comment: @SeanOwen the answer to @ hexafraction is valid for you too, i guess.

Comment: @dystroy I'll try to give more code about it then. I'm sorry for giving so dark explanations.

Comment: @Ingo I don't know what you mean. Do you mean that it's been an error while "compiling"?

Comment: @JavainJavakain No. The two examples should be equivalent. Hence, if (a big IF, if you ask me) they still behave differently, then something else must be wrong. One example is byte code manipulation on program startup.

Comment: @JavainJavakain no you still have not said what "works" about the first one. The source code does not help.

Comment: @Ingo I have the fact that they behave differently, the server sends the long with the 1st. With the 2nd, the client keeps waiting for the long forever until a conection reset exception appears. About byte code manipulation, I tried to browse it and I don't understand the concept yet (I'm sorry I'm newbie with that). I read that applications use it for something but still dont understand. Can you show me something that I can read about it? If it's too complex, nevermind.

Comment: @SeanOwen In the 1st example, the content of the method protoSendLong() writes a long in the output of a socket (that's "it works" for me). In the 2nd example, I don't know if it does it but the receiver doesn't get it (that's "it doesn't work" for me)

Comment: @JavainJavakain Don't worry. Just explain us how you compile the code and what you do then with the code, before it gets executed. To state it thus: can you recreate the behaviour with just using javac, and maybe jar command

Comment: @Ingo OK. When I experienced this problem, I was using Eclipse Europa to execute. I've exported my project into jars and executed both-cases servers, it worked in both :S. Is that enough information or do you need more?

Comment: @JavainJavakain No additional tools, like "optimizers" "code checkers" "obfuscators" or the like?

Comment: @Ingo I don't think so

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference it all in the two snippets with respect to invoking the method. It gets invoked in both cases. If the method doesn't do what you expect in one case or another it is nothing to do with this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the function call inside if statement, we could assume that the function

```
Transfers.protoSendLong
```

return Boolean.

In the code,

```
if(Transfers.protoSendLong(output, date.getTime()))
{
       "do something"
}
```

Thus, "do something" is executed only when the function "Transfers.protoSendLong" returns TRUE. If it returns false "do something" is skipped.

But in case of ,

```
Transfers.protoSendLong(output, date.getTime());
```

TRUE or FALSE maybe returned but nothing would changed the flow of code since there is no if statement or any variable to catch it.

Comment: the thing is what it matters here it's the action of Transfers.protoSendLong(); I don't mind about the boolean at all in this case, though it's useful for something else. What I don't understand is that the action of Transfers.protoSendLong() is done correctly INSIDE the if but not OUTSIDE. I don't know if I explained myself.